# Different version of Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode4.2, xcode3.2

I have a question, I created an IOS app on Xcode 4.2 on virtual machine it was running and everything is OK i tried run it on Xcode 3.2.6 on Mac it shows errors about 422 and GLKit framework and libc++ dylib are not loaded i can't understand the reason and by the way the in the App I’m using Google Map.
Any Solution?!

Comment: Why not upgrade your Xcode on Mac? ;)

Comment: because the old version of ios compatible with xcode 3.2.6

Comment: and i need to run on this version.

Comment: Chances are linking against an SDK that is not in the older os and when you transitioned from Xcode 4 to Xcode 3 it went away and now it won't compile because it is not there to link against. Also unless your client says you need to support an older version Take a look at https://mixpanel.com/trends/#report/ios_7. versions before iOS 6 account for 3% of the market.

Comment: @SaintMacintosh u mean it is not gonna work right??

Comment: when you compile you use libraries/SDK's. This code was written at some point in time. If the library you are using was written after Xcode 3.2.6 and whatever iOS SDK it supports then, no it won't work.